# App script: agregue nueva entrada a la hoja de cálculo con: la carpeta y la URL sin generar una nueva hoja de cálculo

Tags: google-apps-script

Tengo una carpeta principal llamada películas y carpetas secundarias con películas dentro:
películas/luca (2020)/luca-1080.mkv

El script gracias a [idfurw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16125139/idfurw) hace lo siguiente:

- Genera el nombre de la carpeta secundaria (luca (2020))
- Genera el enlace de la película correspondiente (enlace gdrive de la película)
  Este es el script:

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
  
  var folders = foldersID.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var link = file.getUrl();
      sheet.appendRow([name, link]);
    }
  }
}
```

pero:

- Crea una hoja de cálculo cada vez que se lanza (que no quiero eso)

Lo que quiero lograr es:

-Tome una hoja de cálculo desde un ID o nombre

- Si agrego nuevas carpetas con películas a la carpeta principal y cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el script, que solo agrege las que faltan a la hoja de cálculo (nombre y url)

Comment: En este sitio no se deben incluir etiquetas en los títulos de las preguntas (ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), tampoco se deben incluir adornos innecesarios como ❌y ✅ . Si no quieres que se genere una nueva hoja de cálculo cada vez que se ejecuta muestra lo que haz intentado para evitar eso.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La solucion que andaba buscando se encuentra  Aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002836/app-script-add-new-file-to-spreadsheet-with-folder-and-url-no-generate-new-spr

gracias a todos

Este es el script que funciona perfectamente.

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Insert your Google Sheet's ID here");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Get existing names in column A
  var existingNames = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);

  var newData = [];

  if(lastRow == 0){
    //Append header row
    sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
    lastRow++;
  }
  
  var folders = foldersID.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();

    if(existingNames.includes(name)){
      //name already exist in the sheets, Skip
      continue;
    }

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var link = file.getUrl();

      //add new data
      newData.push([name, link]);
    }
  }

  //Write new data to sheets
  if(newData.length>0){
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
}
```